# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How do I fix this error:

Its telling my the error is coming from the first line:

```
    //Putting album art in album placeholder
**Error Here-->** if (album_list_of.get(position).getAlbumCover().contains("content://media/external/audio/albumart")) {
                Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
                Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, Integer.parseInt(album_list_of.get(position).getAlbumPosition()));
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(albumArtUri)
                        .error(R.drawable.no_song_image)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                        .into(album_Cover);
            } else {
                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(album_list_of.get(position).getAlbumCover(), bmOptions);
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    Glide.with(this)
                            .load(bitmap)
                            .error(R.drawable.no_song_image)
                            .into(album_Cover);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes, its the `contains()` and you call it on a null reference. So `getAlbumCover()` returns null here.

Comment: `album_list_of` is apparently null when you get to this line. check for the reason of that.

Comment: Thank you! Very much! This helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`album_list_of.get(position).getAlbumCover()` returns null. add a null check for the value of it

```
String album = album_list_of.get(position).getAlbumCover();

if (album != null)
{
   ...
}
```